# Problem by compiling long table

Tags: xltabular

Im trying to generate a long table that looks like in the annexed picture. For some reason, I', getting the following mistake. I really dont know where the mistake can be. Have maybe someone experience with this type of problem?

[image]

The log error:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\hsize}}

\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} P @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\newcommand\headdefpotential{% Added to avoid repeating parts
    \toprule
    \mytab{\textbf{Region area}} & 
    \mytab{\textbf{Quality class}} &
    \mytab{\textbf{Distance-to-grid}} &
    \mytab{\textbf{PV [km$^2$]}} &
    \mytab{\textbf{PV [GW]}} &
    \mytab{\textbf{Wind [km$^2$]}} &
    \mytab{\textbf{Wind [GW]}} \\
    \midrule}


\begin{document}
\section{Potential area analysis}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}p{0.1\textwidth}p{0.13\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}YYYY@{}}

\caption{Potential area analysis results per technology, model region and applied categorisation}\label{potential analysis}
\headdefpotential\endfirsthead

\caption{Potential area analysis results per technology, model region and applied categorisation \textit{(Continued)}} \\[-2ex]
\headdefpotential\endhead
%%% The footer
\bottomrule\endfoot

CHL0 & Quality class 1  & EE/PtX: GD\_0-2km &  711.98 &  59.33 &4422.83 &110.57 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2-4km &41.50 &3.46 & 354.36 &  8.86 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0-2km & 0.00 &0.00 & 836.08 & 20.90 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2-4km & 0.00 &0.00 &  71.58 &  1.79 \\
     &  & PtX: island & 1197.01 &  99.75 &  18815.82 &470.40 \\
     \cmidrule{2-7}
     & Quality class 2  & EE/PtX: GD\_0-2km & 6808.21 & 567.33 &4290.42 &107.26 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2-4km &  498.66 &  41.55 & 294.84 &  7.37 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0-2km &79.06 &6.59 &3203.33 & 80.08 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2-4km &  637.75 &  53.14 & 257.49 &  6.44 \\
     &  & PtX: island &22140.51 &1844.97 &  16646.72 &416.17 \\
     \cmidrule{2-7}
     & Quality class 3  & EE/PtX: GD\_0-2km & 1905.41 & 158.78 & 713.39 & 17.83 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2-4km &  164.78 &  13.73 &  55.86 &  1.40 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0-2km &  404.59 &  33.71 & 797.14 & 19.93 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2-4km & 3235.32 & 269.60 &  58.23 &  1.46 \\
     &  & PtX: island &17178.89 &1431.52 &5055.52 &126.39 \\
    \midrule
CHL1 & Quality class 1  & EE/PtX: GD\_0-2km & 1238.04 & 103.17 &2638.44 & 65.96 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2-4km &65.65 &5.47 & 166.51 &  4.16 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0-2km &  107.67 &8.97 & 516.03 & 12.90 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2-4km & 2.35 &0.20 &  26.71 &  0.67 \\
     &  & PtX: island & 1698.48 & 141.53 &7753.24 &193.83 \\
     \cmidrule{2-7}
     & Quality class 2  & EE/PtX: GD\_0-2km & 1669.85 & 139.15 & 901.26 & 22.53 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2-4km &90.35 &7.53 &  51.99 &  1.30 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0-2km &  427.50 &  35.62 & 136.97 &  3.42 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2-4km &21.25 &1.77 &   9.43 &  0.24 \\
     &  & PtX: island & 3491.94 & 290.98 &2794.36 & 69.86 \\
     \cmidrule{2-7}
     & Quality class 3  & EE/PtX: GD\_0-2km & 1646.11 & 137.17 &1016.66 & 25.42 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2-4km &  121.23 &  10.10 &  58.78 &  1.47 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0-2km &  159.34 &  13.28 &  41.51 &  1.04 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2-4km &17.56 &1.46 &   5.01 &  0.13 \\
     &  & PtX: island & 6448.14 & 537.32 &1094.38 & 27.36 \\
     \midrule
CHL2 & Quality class 1  & EE/PtX: GD\_0-2km &19.72 &1.64 & 525.33 & 13.13 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2-4km & 0.67 &0.06 &  29.59 &  0.74 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0-2km & 0.00 &0.00 &   2.39 &  0.06 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2-4km & 0.00 &0.00 &   0.87 &  0.02 \\
     &  & PtX: island &  123.64 &  10.30 &1225.14 & 30.63 \\
     \cmidrule{2-7}
     & Quality class 2  & EE/PtX: GD\_0-2km &  406.13 &  33.84 & 345.18 &  8.63 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2-4km &22.65 &1.89 &  28.07 &  0.70 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0-2km & 0.00 &0.00 &  30.51 &  0.76 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2-4km & 0.00 &0.00 &   1.49 &  0.04 \\
     &  & PtX: island &  269.63 &  22.47 &3067.61 & 76.69 \\
     \cmidrule{2-7}
     & Quality class 3  & EE/PtX: GD\_0-2km & 0.00 &0.00 & 990.36 & 24.76 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2-4km & 0.00 &0.00 &  76.24 &  1.91 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0-2km & 0.00 &0.00 &   0.14 &  0.00 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2-4km & 0.00 &0.00 &   0.00 &  0.00 \\
     &  & PtX: island &  390.59 &  32.55 &9541.80 &238.55 \\
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not give the error shown. it gives `! Misplaced \noalign.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code the OP posted does not give rise to the error message shown above. The `! Misplaced \noalign.` message, which does indicate that there's a problem, is caused by the lack of a `\\` directive at the end of the line

```
\caption{Potential area analysis...}\label{potential analysis}
```

Here's a solution that fixes this issue and applies a few addtional tweaks to the code, including aligning the numbers in the four data columns on their decimal markers, simplifying the material in column 2, not allowing line breaks in column 3, and replacing the `\cmidrule` directives with `\addlinespace` (to create a more open and inviting "look").

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltabular} % for 'xltabular' environment
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for \smash[b] macro
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % \Centering & \RaggedRight macros

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\RaggedRight}p{\hsize}}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\Centering}p{\hsize}}

\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} Q @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
   
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1,group-digits=false]}
\newcommand\mY[1]{\multicolumn{1}{Y}{#1}}

\newcommand\headdefpotential{% Added to avoid repeating parts
\toprule
    \mytab{{Region area}} & 
    \mytab{{Quality class}} &
    {Distance to grid} &
    \mY{{PV} [km\textsuperscript{2}]} &
    \mY{{PV} [GW]} &
    \mY{{Wind} [km\textsuperscript{2}]} &
    \mY{{Wind} [GW]}  \\
\midrule}


\begin{document}

\section{Potential area analysis}
\enlargethispage{0.5\baselineskip} % optional

\begingroup %localize scope of next 2 instructions
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} 
  p{0.1\textwidth} 
  >{\Centering}p{0.1\textwidth} 
  l T{5.2} T{4.2} T{5.2} T{3.2} @{}}

\caption{Potential area analysis results per technology, 
         model region and applied categorisation}
\label{potential analysis} \\ % <-- " \\" is new
\headdefpotential
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{7}{@{}l@{}}{Table \thetable, continued} \\[0.5ex]
\headdefpotential
\endhead

%%% The footers

\multicolumn{7}{r@{}}{\itshape\small(cont'd on next page)} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

CHL0 & 1& EE/PtX: GD\_0--2km &   711.98 &   59.33 &  4422.83 & 110.57 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2--4km &    41.50 &    3.46 &   354.36 &   8.86 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0--2km     &     0.00 &    0.00 &   836.08 &  20.90 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2--4km     &     0.00 &    0.00 &    71.58 &   1.79 \\
     &  & PtX: island        &  1197.01 &   99.75 & 18815.82 & 470.40 \\
     \addlinespace 
     & 2& EE/PtX: GD\_0--2km &  6808.21 &  567.33 &  4290.42 & 107.26 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2--4km &   498.66 &   41.55 &   294.84 &   7.37 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0--2km     &    79.06 &    6.59 &  3203.33 &  80.08 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2--4km     &   637.75 &   53.14 &   257.49 &   6.44 \\
     &  & PtX: island        & 22140.51 & 1844.97 & 16646.72 & 416.17 \\
     \addlinespace 
     & 3& EE/PtX: GD\_0--2km &  1905.41 &  158.78 &   713.39 &  17.83 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2--4km &   164.78 &   13.73 &    55.86 &   1.40 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0--2km     &   404.59 &   33.71 &   797.14 &  19.93 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2--4km     &  3235.32 &  269.60 &    58.23 &   1.46 \\
     &  & PtX: island        & 17178.89 & 1431.52 &  5055.52 & 126.39 \\
\midrule
CHL1 & 1& EE/PtX: GD\_0--2km &  1238.04 &  103.17 &  2638.44 &  65.96 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2--4km &    65.65 &    5.47 &   166.51 &   4.16 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0--2km     &   107.67 &    8.97 &   516.03 &  12.90 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2--4km     &     2.35 &    0.20 &    26.71 &   0.67 \\
     &  & PtX: island        &  1698.48 &  141.53 &  7753.24 & 193.83 \\
     \addlinespace 
     & 2& EE/PtX: GD\_0--2km &  1669.85 &  139.15 &   901.26 &  22.53 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2--4km &    90.35 &    7.53 &    51.99 &   1.30 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0--2km     &   427.50 &   35.62 &   136.97 &   3.42 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2--4km     &    21.25 &    1.77 &     9.43 &   0.24 \\
     &  & PtX: island        &  3491.94 &  290.98 &  2794.36 &  69.86 \\
     \addlinespace 
     & 3& EE/PtX: GD\_0--2km &  1646.11 &  137.17 &  1016.66 &  25.42 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2--4km &   121.23 &   10.10 &    58.78 &   1.47 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0--2km     &   159.34 &   13.28 &    41.51 &   1.04 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2--4km     &    17.56 &    1.46 &     5.01 &   0.13 \\
     &  & PtX: island        &  6448.14 &  537.32 &  1094.38 &  27.36 \\
\midrule
CHL2 & 1& EE/PtX: GD\_0--2km &    19.72 &    1.64 &   525.33 &  13.13 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2--4km &     0.67 &    0.06 &    29.59 &   0.74 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0--2km     &     0.00 &    0.00 &     2.39 &   0.06 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2--4km     &     0.00 &    0.00 &     0.87 &   0.02 \\
     &  & PtX: island        &   123.64 &   10.30 &  1225.14 &  30.63 \\
     % \addlinespace % occurs at page break
     & 2& EE/PtX: GD\_0--2km &   406.13 &   33.84 &   345.18 &   8.63 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2--4km &    22.65 &    1.89 &    28.07 &   0.70 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0--2km     &     0.00 &    0.00 &    30.51 &   0.76 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2--4km     &     0.00 &    0.00 &     1.49 &   0.04 \\
     &  & PtX: island        &   269.63 &   22.47 &  3067.61 &  76.69 \\
     \addlinespace 
     & 3& EE/PtX: GD\_0--2km &     0.00 &    0.00 &   990.36 &  24.76 \\
     &  & EE/PtX: GD\_2--4km &     0.00 &    0.00 &    76.24 &   1.91 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_0--2km     &     0.00 &    0.00 &     0.14 &   0.00 \\
     &  & EE: GD\_2--4km     &     0.00 &    0.00 &     0.00 &   0.00 \\
     &  & PtX: island        &   390.59 &   32.55 &  9541.80 & 238.55 \\

\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey Mico, thanks for answering. Could you please explain what this do: \begingroup %localize scope of next 2 instructions
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}

Comment: I also wanted to ask if you know what could be the reason that my table is wider than the page margin. On a separate test project, it compiles perfectly, might it be conflicting with other packages?

Comment: @Master_student_H2 - Stuff between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements forms a "TeX group", implifying that the scope of the instructions `\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}` and `\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}` is that group. This is useful in case you need different values for `\tabcolsep`and `\LTcapwidth` to apply elsewhere in the document and don't want ot reset the parameter values by hand. If the table is too wide, give `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` a try.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The code works fine. I just had to adjust older \newcommand so it wouldnt affect my code.